# Selecting a subset of a dataframe based on a list - pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am working with a large dataframe (ftp://ftp.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/genomes/refseq/bacteria/assembly_summary.txt) with pandas in Python 3, using PyCharm. The column that I'm interested in for now is called 'taxid'. I want to go through the dataframe and keep only the rows in which the 'taxid' value can be found in another list that I am giving the program. Not all of the items in the list will be in the dataframe.

My current issue:
I have tried using a small, sample list ( `nodes_list=['1707289', '251229','14']` ) and it does not work. From my tries at debugging, I can tell that this appears to be somehow related to apostrophes.

`print(data[data['taxid'].isin([1707289, 251229, 14])])` gives me the expected values.

However,

`print(data[data['taxid'].isin(['1707289', '251229', '14'])])` or `print(data[data['taxid'].isin(nodes_list)])` give me an empty dataframe, with an empty index.

I do not know how to fix this and would appreciate your help!

Comment: if this happens then the `taxid` column is made of integers... you're asking pandas if an integer is in a list of strings, and it gives you the correct answer (no). Why are you declaring `nodes_list` as a list of strings? Depending on what you need to do, you either have to convert the `taxid` column of the dataframe to strings, or declare `nodes_list` as a list of integers.

Comment: It's obvious that `1707289!='1707289'`. If you want to use string to compare, you can use `data[data['taxid'].astype(str).isin(['1707289', '251229', '14'])]`.

Comment: Thank you @Ynjxsjmh and albjerto. I now realize it was the type of data (str / int) that was different. Much appreciated - problem fixed.